# Find the column location of an element each each row of a matrix, and storing in matrix

Tags: matlab

I have an n x m matrix with -1s and 1s in each row.
I wish to find the column index of -1s and 1s iterating through each row.
The output should be a matrix of same size n x m

M=[1 1 -1 1 -1;-1 1 1 -1 1 ;1 -1 1 -1 -1];

I have tried the following without luck

```
inputMatrix=M(1:end,:);

outputMatrix=zeros(size((M)));
for i =1:size(M,1)
temp=zeros(size((M)));
[~,j] = find(M == -1);
outputMatrix=j; 
end
```

The expected result should be

outputMatrix = [1 2 4;2 3 5;1 3]

Comment: Can you show us the expected output for your sample matrix `M`?

Comment: i would like a matrix of same dimensions as input matrix

Comment: I read that in the question. So you're looking for a logical array with 1 in each location containing a -1 in the input array?

Comment: What do you think `inputMatrix=M(1:end,:);` does? Please provide the exact expected output matrix for your given input

Comment: ,..sorry, the output matrix should be

Comment: outputMatrix = [1 2 4;2 3 5;1 3]

Comment: In your code, you're overwriting `outputMatrix` in every iteration.

Comment: A matrix needs to have equal number of elements in each row/column. Your expected result has only two elements in the third row. Your `outputMatrix` is not a matrix

Comment: understood, but the question remains i wish to iterate through each row and return the location of the resultant find instruction.

Comment: So what exactly is your expected result?

Comment: thank you this helped me aot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result cannot be a matrix, as noted in comments. You can use a cell array:

```
M = [1 1 -1 1 -1;-1 1 1 -1 1 ;1 -1 1 -1 -1];
[ii, jj] = find(M==1);
result = accumarray(ii, jj, [size(M,1) 1], @(x) {sort(x.')});
```

This gives

```
>> celldisp(result)
result{1} =
     1     2     4
result{2} =
     2     3     5
result{3} =
     1     3
```